# Nullable<long> is allowing adding string values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and i have the following property inside my model class :-

```
 public Nullable<long> TOTALMEMORY { get; set; }
```

I was assuming that the model state will show a message in-case the user tries to insert a string inside this property, but the model state will not raise any error (client side OR server side) when i try to insert a string inside the TOTALMEMORY field, and the DB will raise an exception ? any advise how to force such a validation ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is how the view look like:-

```
<div >
    <span class="f"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY) </span> 

    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY) <i class=" icon icon-blue icon-star-on "></i>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY)

</div>
```

and the post action method :-

```
public ActionResult Create(ServerJoin sj, FormCollection formValues)
        {
          //code goes here
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
```

Comment: the model wouldn't bind to that property if the value on the form is not of a null or long type. for example, if the field TOTALMEMORY on the form was an input and you entered "abc123", it will fail - because abc123 is NOT of type long.

Comment: What does your view look like where you're using this property? Please only post the relevant lines and not the entire view. Also include the controller action method signature.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas this what i though the behaviour will be. but no validation error is being displayed if i enter string, and the exception will be raised on the DB..

Comment: what DB exception? the model will not bind if the datatype is incorrect. look at the field type of the column in the DB and its constraints in addition to what is actually being set in your property